# File include error in jsp

Tags: jsp, filenotfoundexception, jspinclude

I have linux shared hosting. When i host my website it gives me an error: 
HTTP Status 500 - /user-login-process.jsp (line: 1, column: 2) File "../connection.jsp" not found

Dir structure
root
-connection.jsp

root
-process
--user-login-process.jsp
where I include my file. 
Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: does it work on localhost ?

Comment: yes. Its work fine in localhost. I have window 7 in local machine

Comment: can u add source code of the includes

Comment: hmmm seems you are having this problem for the last 20 days or more , file permission does not look an issue looking at the other post

Comment: <%@ include file="../connection.jsp"%> this is my include code. I check permission status 777 still doesn't work.

Comment: permission 777 is a **bad** practice and it must work without it

Comment: if it works inwindows7 and not on linuix can you check server logs... apache has few logs